# Docker port not being exposed

Tags: docker

Using Windows and I have pulled the Jenkins image successfully via

```
docker pull jenkins
```

I am running a new container via following command and it seems to start the container fine. But when I try to access the Jenkins page on my browser, I just get following error message. I was expecting to see the Jenkins main log in page. Same issue when I tried other images like Redis, Couchbase and JBoss/Wildfly. What am I doing wrong? New to Docker and following tutorials which has described the following command to expose ports. Same for some answers given here + docs. Please advice. Thanks.

```
docker run -tid -p 127.0.0.1:8097:8097 --name jen1 --rm jenkins
```

In browser, just getting a normal 'Problem Loading page Error'.

```
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your command does is connects your host port 8097 with jenkins image port 8097, but how do you know that the image exposes/uses port 8097 (spoiler: it doesn't).

This image uses port 8080, so you want to port your local 8097 to port that one.

Change the command to this:

```
docker run -tid -p 127.0.0.1:8097:8080 --name jen1 --rm jenkins
```

Just tested your command with this small fix, and it works locally for me.

Answer (score 3):

First, it looks a little bit strange use `-tid`. Since you're trying to run it detached, maybe, it'd be better just `-d`, and use `-ti` for example to access via shell `docker exec -ti jen1 bash`.

Second, docker localhost is not the same than host localhost, so, I'd run the container directly without 127.0.0.1. If you want to use it, you may specify `--net=host`, what makes 127.0.0.1 is the same inside and outside docker.

Third, try to access first through port 8080 for initial admin password.

Definitively, in summary:

```
docker run -d -p 8097:8080 --name jen1 --rm jenkins
```

Then,
http://172.17.0.2:8080/

Finally, unlock Jenkins setting admin password. You can have a look at starting logs: `docker logs jen1`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Jenkins Dockerfile [from here](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins):

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git curl && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ARG user=jenkins
ARG group=jenkins
ARG uid=1000
ARG gid=1000
ARG http_port=8080
ARG agent_port=50000
.....
.....
# for main web interface:
EXPOSE ${http_port}

# will be used by attached slave agents:
EXPOSE ${agent_port}
```

As you can see port 8080 is being exposed and not 8097.
Change your command to

`docker run -tid -p 8097:8080 --name jen1 --rm jenkins`