# Docker port not being exposed with the web browser but works with curl

Tags: docker

I have created a local application and build a docker container from this app https://spliceailookup-api.broadinstitute.org/

When I run in a new terminal (outside the container): `curl "http://localhost:8080/spliceai/?hg=38&distance=500&mask=0&precomputed=1&variant=chr8-140300615-C-G"`
I get a correct response.

However, in the web browser I get the

```
This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

This is my run command

```
docker run -v /home/manuel.dominguez/reference_files/:/Users/jocotton/Desktop/references_files/ -p 8080:8080 --net=host -it spliceai

# I have just recently learnt that --net=host the -p is not needed
# not familiar about this but the --net=host is needed otherwise the 
# previous curl command outside the container does't work
```

and this is my Dockerfile

WORKDIR /Users/jocotton/Desktop/SpliceAI-lookup

```
ADD . .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
# RUN pip install setuptools==19.2
RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools==57.5.0
RUN pip install -r requirementsManuel.txt

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ./start_local_server.sh
```

and just in case, this is the `start_local_server.sh`

```
set -x

NUM_THREADS=1
HOST=127.0.0.1
PORT=8080
TIMEOUT=1800
gunicorn -w ${NUM_THREADS} -t ${TIMEOUT} -b ${HOST}:${PORT}  server:app
```

I have tried all recommendation given here [Docker port not being exposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63229280/docker-port-not-being-exposed) but not of them seems to work.

Comment: Have you checked the HTTP scheme? (Browsers often eager to switch to HTTPS instead of HTTP which results in the same error) BTW why do you use net=host option? (Bind gunicorn to 0.0.0.0:8080 with -b to allow all source IPs with -p on docker run.)

Comment: `HOST=127.0.0.1` This is the problem.  Docker containers have their own localhost interface.  You need to listen on 0.0.0.0 if you want to be able to forward ports.  Just like on the host, the container's 127.0.0.1 is not routable through the docker network or any other network.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. What shall I put in -p on docker 8080:8080 and what shall I put in -b 0.0.0.0??